# python calculate the position of the largest and smallest elements of the list. Nonetype error

Tags: python, list

Im having issue with the last function in this program, position. i have to calculate the position of the largest and smallest numbers in the list but i keep getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. How do i fix this? Thanks.

```
def main():
    data = getnumbers()
    top, bottom = calculate(data)
    pos1, pos2 = position(data, top, bottom)


    print("The numbers are,", data)
    print("The largest and lowest numbers are,", top, "and", bottom)
    print("The position of the largest number is,", pos1, "and the position of the smallest number is,", pos2, ".")


def getnumbers():
    nums = []
    xStr = input("Enter a number (<Enter> to quit) >> ")
    while xStr != "":
        x = eval(xStr)
        nums.append(x)   
        xStr = input("Enter a number (<Enter> to quit) >> ")
    return nums


def calculate(nums):
    top = max(nums)
    bottom = min(nums)
    return top, bottom

def position(nums, top, bottom):
    pos1 = nums.index(top)
    pos2 = nums.index(bottom)



main()
```

Comment: You should absolutely not be using `eval` in this case. A user could enter potentially harmful code that would be executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never explicitly return anything from `position()`, so `None` is returned. And then it is iterated over in order to assign to `pos1` and `pos2`.